# ASP.NET Core: Error while Updating Migration (Database first approach)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have created an application in .NET Core where I am trying with database first approach.

I was able to add Migration using "Add-Migration InitialCreate" but when I am trying to create a database in SQL Server using " Update-Database" I am getting the below error.

> **Login failed for user ''**.

Below is my content from `appsettings.json` file

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DevConnection": "Server=(local)\\sqlexpress;Database=Mydatabase:Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
  }
}
```

**Just FYI**
Also I was facing issue to create migration so I have added below code after that I was able to create migrations.

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
{
    public MyDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection");
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        return new MyDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

1. SQL Server Version: 18.4
2. .NET Core Version: 3.1.2
3. I am trying with windows authentication

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the connection string to: `"DevConnection": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Mydatabase:Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"`. In this way it works for me!

Comment: Oh wait, isn't the problem that you are using "DefaultConnection" in the `CreateDbContext` function and that it is called "DevConnection" in the `appsettings.json` file?

Comment: Apology, i am using DevConnection not DefaultConnection in the CreateDbContext and that is calling my DevConnection in "appsettings.json" file. I just made the correction above.

Answer (score 0):

Use for Database first Approach Entity Framework Core In ASP.NET Core MVC

**Step 1:Add Packages in your project:**

1.Add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`
2.Add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`
3.Add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`

**Step 2: Add Migration command in Package Manager Console:**

```
 Scaffold-DbContext "Server=Server name;Database=Database name;User
 Id=User name;Password=password;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```